# What does this determinant mean?

Tags: matrices, determinant, mathematical-modeling

I have the following Jacobian matrix for an equilibrium of an SIR model
$$J=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\text{$\alpha $N} & 0 & \zeta  & 0 \\
 \text{$\alpha $N} & -\beta -\rho  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \beta  & -\zeta  & 0 \\
 0 & \rho  & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, when using Mathematica to calculate $\det{(J- \lambda I)}$, I get the following

$$\lambda ^3 \left(\lambda -4 \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\text{$\alpha $N} & 0 & \zeta  & 0 \\
 \text{$\alpha $N} & -\beta -\rho  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \beta  & -\zeta  & 0 \\
 0 & \rho  & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)$$

What does this mean? Why is it giving me a matrix back in the determinant? I need to find the determinant in order to analyse the stability of an equilibrium.

Here is my code

> $In[1]:= \text{J2}\text{:=}\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -\text{$\alpha $N} & 0 & \zeta  & 0 \\
>  \text{$\alpha $N} & -\beta -\rho  & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \beta  & -\zeta  & 0 \\
>  0 & \rho  & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> $In[2]:= \text{FullSimplify}[\left| \text{J2}-\lambda  \text{IdentityMatrix}[4]\right| ]$

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: @AlexR. - Edited the post with my code

Comment: depending on the typset, try $\lambda$*IdentityMatrix[4], and also try Det[ ]  instead of $||$.

Comment: @AlexR. I tried that as well, it gives the same :(

Comment: What happens if you type your matrix J2 in terms as $\{\{-\alpha N, 0, \zeta, 0\},\{\alpha N, -\beta-\rho, 0 , 0\},\cdots\}\}$

Comment: That worked! :). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you type your matrix J2 in terms as $\{\{-\alpha N, 0, \zeta, 0\},\{\alpha N, -\beta-\rho, 0 , 0\},\cdots\}\}$

Comment: Thank you! :). It seems as if Mathematica is not too fond of Matrixform when calculating determinants :)